# jQuery Children vs Sibling(s) with $(this) as the selector parent element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child, siblings

Ok, I suspect there will be dozens of these on my page so I am trying to build a single function to handle them properly without having to recycle code over and over and changing the IDs or class names of elements just to make this work.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="button_select">
    <ul class="button_select_toggle">
        <li>
            <div class="button_select_text">Menu Text</div><div class="button_select_arrow">V</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="button_select_sub" rel="hidden">
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And what I am trying to do currently is get specifically the UL with the class button_select_sub so I can get its rel value. Which yes to some extent this would be easy if this was going to be the only one on any given page, however this is going to be on any given page who knows how many times. Hence me trying to make the universal function for handling them. Anyway my last failed attempt was:

```
var selectstatus = $(this).siblings('.button_select_sub').attr('rel');
alert('status: '+selectstatus);
```

but in the alert I am getting "status: undefined" maybe im not using siblings correctly? maybe theres an alternative option. Also worth mentioning is button_select_sub might not always be the last UL in the div so I can't do :last either.

ive also tried, children().find().. and a couple others, I know its possible I just can't chain it together right.

Comment: What is `$(this)` referencing? Can you post the whole js code?

Comment: sorry, $(this) is referencing the div "button_select"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `$(this)` is referring to div "button_select" then I think you should be using `children` not `siblings`.

```
var selectstatus = $(this).children('.button_select_sub').attr('rel');
alert('status: '+selectstatus);
```

Comment: That was it.. guess my mistake was using find() chained to the children() cause I didn't think I could use a class selector in the children(), unchained find() and it works nicely, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `$(this)` is referencing `.button-select` then `siblings` is not what you should use.
You should use `children` or `find` but `children().find()` makes no sense here.
Also, if there are many `.button_select_sub` you should iterate with `each` and extract each individual `rel` value.

```
$('.button_select')
    .find('.button_select_sub')
    .each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('rel'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selectstatus = "";

    $('.button_select').click(function(){

         selectstatus = $(this).children('ul.button_select_sub').attr('rel');
         alert('status: '+selectstatus);
    });

});
```

If you have more than a single `.button_select_sub` you might want to run an each statement, though that may cause a number of alerts to pop up.